# How do i call a function on a Service from a Controller, on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I am trying to call a function on a Service from a controller, in order to update the theme on my website, depending on which provider's section of the site i am on.

**My Service,**

```
MyApp.service('ThemeService', function() {

    var ThemeProvider = 1; 
    var ThemeArea = "NotSet";

    this.SetVariables = function() {
        switch (ThemeProvider) {
        case 1: 
        default:
            ThemeArea = "Themes/Default";
            break;

        case 2: 
            ThemeArea = "Themes/Provider2";
            break;
        }

        return ThemeProvider;
    };

return {
        ThemeProvider: ThemeProvider,
        getThemeArea: ThemeArea,
    };
});
```

**My Controller**

```
$scope.loadData = function (input) {
ThemeService.ThemeProvider = 2;
ThemeService.SetVariables();
};
```

My idea is that inside the controller, the function "SetVariables" can be called after the "ThemeProvider" is set, to change the "ThemeArea", but i cant work out how to call the function "SetVariables" from my controller.

When i try, i get an error

> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'SetVariables'

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning `SetVariables`, see at the bottom of your Service definition there's a return statement, it should contain everything you want to be accessible.

```
return {
    ThemeProvider: ThemeProvider,
    getThemeArea: ThemeArea,
    SetVariables: SetVariables
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your service returns an object which does not have any property called `SetVariables`, that's why you get the error.Also `this.SetVariables` will be looking for `ThemeProvider` which is initialized in your service (`var ThemeProvider = 1;`) and not the value assigned from controller.

Your code should be looking like this:

Service:

```
MyApp.service('ThemeService', function() {

    var _ThemeProvider = 1;
    var _ThemeArea = "NotSet";

    angular.extend(this, {
        SetVariables,
        setThemeProvider,
        setThemeArea,
        getThemeProvider,
        getThemeArea
    })

    function SetVariables() {
        switch (_ThemeProvider) {
            case 1:
            default:
                _ThemeArea = "Themes/Default";
                break;

            case 2:
                _ThemeArea = "Themes/Provider2";
                break;
        }

        return _ThemeProvider;
    };

    function setThemeProvider(val) {
        _ThemeProvider = val;
    };

    function getThemeProvider() {
        return _ThemeProvider;
    };

    function setThemeArea(val) {
        _ThemeArea = val;
    }

    function getThemeArea() {
        return _ThemeArea;
    }

});
```

Controller:

```
$scope.loadData = function(input) {
    ThemeService.setThemeProvider(2);
    ThemeService.SetVariables();
};
```